# Check if a double > 1 is divisible by a double < 1

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check if a double (time) > 1 is divisible by another double (samplePeriod) which is > 0 and < 1. The following code works for samplePeriods > 1, but not < 1. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Check if a sample is within 1/10 of a samplePeriod from being on a samplePeriod
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="time"> The time of the sample </param>
    /// <param name="samplePeriod"> The period between samples </param>
    /// <returns> True if the sample is on a sample period, false if not </returns>
    public static bool SampleIsOnSamplePeriod(double time, double samplePeriod)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(time%samplePeriod - 0d) > (samplePeriod/10))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: To be clear - you want to know if the result of dividing doubles `a` and `b` is a _whole number_, right?

Comment: How are you defining "divisible"? Doubles are floating point in C#, so  "perfectly divisible" is going to be quite rare.

Comment: Not quite. The sample period can be any number between 0 and 1. The application is data collection, where I am collecting data at a given frequency, we'll say 10 Hz. The period between samples for 10 Hz is 0.1 seconds (1/freq). So, I want to see if the current time "time" lies on an increment of 0.1 seconds. The allowable error is 1/10th of a sample period, so time can be within +/- 0.01 an be deemed true. Values outside of +/- 0.01 would be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static bool SampleIsOnSamplePeriod(double time, double samplePeriod)
{
    double mod1 = (time / samplePeriod) % 1;
    return (mod1 < .1) || (mod1 > .9);
}
```

Basically you are dividing `time` by `samplePeriod` and then doing a mod by 1. If it is "close enough", then this value should be between 0 and 0.1 or between 0.9 and 1.

The left side of the check is checking [0, 0.1]. The right side is for [0.9, 1].

Comment: This answer does not work because `mod1` is already computed by dividing by `sameplePeriod`. It should really be compared to `0.1` and `0.9`, not to `samplePeriod / 10` and `1 - (samplePeriod / 10)`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq True. I don't know how I got that wrong.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comment “The allowable error is 1/10th of a sample period, so time can be within +/- 0.01 an be deemed true. Values outside of +/- 0.01 would be false.”, I really think that you want:

```
if ((time%samplePeriod > samplePeriod*0.9d) || (time%samplePeriod < samplePeriod*0.1d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool SampleIsOnSamplePeriod(double time, double samplePeriod)
{
    var d = time / samplePediod;
    return Math.Abs(d - Math.Round(d)) <= 0.1;
}
```